# How to limit strings in Pandas row by row using apply and lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, string, lambda

I have the following dataframe:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['1', "Tag1, Tag323, Tag36"], ['2', "Tag11, Tag212"], ['4', "Tag1, Tag12, Tag3, Tag324"]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Tag'])
```

```
print(df)

    ID  Tag
    1   Tag1, Tag323, Tag36
    2   Tag11, Tag212
    4   Tag1, Tag12, Tag3, Tag324
```

I would like to manipulate the string values (e.g. `"Tag1, Tag2, Tag3"`) in column `tag` with the follwing condition. In each row, if there are more than 2 tags, the output should look like `"Tag1, Tag2 .."`. The tag length can be different.

```
print(df)

    ID  Tag
    1   Tag1, Tag323 ..
    2   Tag11, Tag212
    4   Tag1, Tag12 ..
```

Does anyone know a Pandas apply and lambda method to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is split tags by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and if length is greater like `N` select first `N` values and join:

```
N = 2
s = df['Tag'].str.split(",")
df['Tag'] = df['Tag'].mask(s.str.len().gt(N), s.str[:N].str.join(",") + "...")
print (df)
  ID              Tag
0  1  Tag1, Tag323...
1  2    Tag11, Tag212
2  4   Tag1, Tag12...
```

Solution with `apply`:

```
N = 2
df['Tag'] = df['Tag'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.split(',')[:N]) + '...'
                            if x.count(',') + 1 > N else x)
```

Or:

```
N = 2
df['Tag'] = df['Tag'].mask(df['Tag'].str.count(',').gt(N), 
                           df['Tag'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.split(',')[:N]) + '...'))
```

Comment: Solution with apply works perfectly. Thank you! Thereby I am also able to set the number of elements easily without regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
len_ = len('Tag1, Tag2, Tag3')    
df['Tag'] = [x if len(x)<len_ else "Tag1, Tag2 .." for x in df['Tag']  ]
```

You can choose your own length.

Output:

```
    ID  Tag
0   1   Tag1, Tag2 ..
1   2   Tag1, Tag2
2   4   Tag1, Tag2 ..
```

Comment: I made an edit because tags can have a different length like e.g. Tag1422. Maybe it's possible with counting elements?

Comment: @Daniel you can choose your own threshold setting `len_`

Answer (score 1):

The ol’ `split` and `join` Methods might just work here. I’ll write the whole function below but this can be converted into a lambda function as well

```
def tag_splitter(text):
    split_text = text.split(',')
    if len(split_text) > 2:
        return ','.join(split_text[:2]) + '..'
    return ','.join(split_text)
```

When finished, `apply` this to your column (like `df[‘tag’].apply(tag_splitter)`)

Also, the quotation marks appear wrong on my screen (but I can’t currently change them). Make sure to use the proper single quotes

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way

```
import re
import pandas as pd
data = [['1', "Tag1, Tag323, Tag36"], ['2', "Tag11, Tag212"], ['4', "Tag1, Tag12, Tag3, Tag324"]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Tag'])
def shorten(text):
    return re.sub(r'(\S+,\s+\S+),\s+\S+.*', r'\1..', text)
df['Tag'] = df['Tag'].apply(shorten)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
  ID             Tag
0  1  Tag1, Tag323..
1  2   Tag11, Tag212
2  4   Tag1, Tag12..
```

Explanation: I use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function with capturing group, meaning of symbol is as follows: `(`...`)` - capturing group `\S` - non-whitespace character `\s` - whitespace character `+` - one-or-more repetitions `.` - zero or more repetitions `.` - any character, `,` - literal comma. If found text does containg regular expression, i.e. at least 3 non-whitespace runs, then it is replace by two first runs and what is between them at two dots, other text remain unaffected.

Comment: This seems to work. For simplicity I said after 2 tags the cut should take place. What do I have to do if I need the cut after 6 tags?

Comment: @Daniel you need to alter what is inside capture group, if you would need after 3 tags it would be `(\S+,\s+\S+,\s+\S+)` if after 4 tags it would be `(\S+,\s+\S+,\s+\S+,\s+\S+)` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Just use this simple code:

```
for i in df.Tag:
    a = i.split(",")
    if len(a)>2:
        b = a[0:2]
        c = ",".join(b)+".."
        df["Tag"] = c
```